# Summing up a list of IO Float: [IO Float] in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, sum, monads

So I'm fooling around a bit with Haskell, trying to learn it by myself. I'm trying to solve a certain question where I'm supposed to create a list of random numbers and then sum them up.

I have the code to generate them - using `getStdRandom` and `randomR`. Using them both returns a list of `IO Float`: `[IO Float]`

Now, when I try to sum up the list using say foldl or foldr, or even trying a simple recursion summation, I get errors and such - to my understanding this is because `IO Float` is a monad, so I need to do some Haskell magic to get it to work.

I've been googling around and haven't found something that works.

Is there any way to sum up the list? or even convert it into a list of floats so that its easier to work around in other parts of the code?

Comment: please add the code you have - the solution might be as simple as `sum <$> whateverYouHaveNow`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that a list with type `[IO Float]` is **not** a list of numbers. It is a list of I/O actions that *generate* numbers. The I/O wasn't executed yet, so in your case the random number generator hasn't actually generated the numbers.

You can use the [`sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sequence) function to combine the list of IO actions into a single IO action that provides a list of results:

```
do the_numbers <- sequence your_list
   return $ sum the_numbers
```

Alternatively you could use the [`foldM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:foldM) function to write a monadic fold:

```
sumIONumbers :: [IO Float] -> IO Float
sumIONumbers xs = foldM f 0.0 xs
  where
    f acc mVal = do
      val <- mVal  -- extract the Float from the IO
      return $ acc + val
```

---

As noted in the comments you can also make use of the fact that every `Monad` is also a `Functor` (this is enforced in newer versions) and thus you can use [`fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fmap) to apply a function inside the IO:

```
fmap sum (sequence your_list)
```

Or use the infix synonym [`<$>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--36--62-):

```
sum <$> sequence your_list
```

Comment: That first `do` statement could be simplified to `fmap sum (sequence yourList)` or `sum <$> sequence yourList`. (Where [`fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fmap) and `(<$>) = fmap`)

Comment: “**not** a list of numbers” – exactly. An easy way to see this is to evaluate `sequence your_list` multiple times: you'll get a different result each time!

Answer (score 1):

How about something like the following using liftM:

```
import System.Random
import Control.Monad

rnd :: IO Float
rnd = getStdRandom (randomR (0.0,1.0))

main = do
  let l = map (\_ -> rnd) [1..10]
  n <- foldl (liftM2 (+)) (return (0 :: Float)) l
  print n
```